# Tell windows to process all but one message

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I have a function triggered by a message(WM_ONDATA defined by me) the function will execute this code :

```
MSG msg;
while(::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) 
{

    if( !AfxGetApp()->PumpMessage() )
    { 
        ::PostQuitMessage(0); 
        return 0; 
    } 
}
return 1;
```

The problem is that there could be on the message queue another message that could trigger the function.

I'm wondering if I can make it process all the message but WM_ONDATA?

Comment: It sounds like there may be something wrong with your design here.

Comment: This is a really elaborate way to make PostMessage work like SendMessage.  Just use SendMessage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the window proc to ignore the message or to queue it's execution. If you're just looking to avoid recursion, have a reentrance lock

```
 class MyDlg : ...
 {
       MyDlg(...) : m_inOnData(false), ... { .... }

       ...
     private:
        BOOL m_inOnData;
 };
```

....

```
 void MyDlg::OnOnData(...)
 {
      if (m_inOnData)
          return;
      m_inOnData = TRUE;
      ....

      m_inOnData = FALSE;
 }
```

You could get fancy with a scoped RIIA struct (so things will be exception safe and slightly less verbose)

Answer (score 3):

Recall that the third and fourth parameters to PeekMessage let you specify a range of message values. Messages outside that range won't be processed.

```
while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, WM_ONDATA - 1, PM_NOREMOVE)
    || PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_ONDATA + 1, 0xffff, PM_NOREMOVE))
```

Comment: A possible problem with this is that it will process messages out of order. All the 0..WM_ONDATA-1 messages will be done first, and then all the WM_ONDATA+1..0xffff will be processed. That may not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just check the message number in msg after receipt.